# Расположить внутренний div (кнопка) внизу внешнего div (столбец Bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap

Создаю 3 колонки (col-sm-4), [благодаря CSS](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/) для класса .row-eq-height эти колонки имеют одинаковую высоту.

Кнопка в каждой колонке по понятным причинам располагается сразу после текста и так как количество текста разное, кнопки находятся в разных позициях относительно друг друга.

Чтобы сделать кнопки на одной линии хочу расположить их внизу внешнего div (col-sm-4), для этого использую [данную инструкцию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135974/lock-element-to-bottom-of-containing-div), в результате кнопки располагаются на одной линии, но начинают наползать на текст.

Как добиться нужного результата?

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-eq-height">
 <div class="col-sm-4">
  <h3><span class="label label-primary">1</span> Заголовок</h3>
  <p>Текст</p>
  <div class="button">
   <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
  <h3><span class="label label-primary">2</span> Заголовок</h3>
  <p>Текст</p>
  <div class="button">
   <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
  <h3><span class="label label-primary">3</span> Заголовок</h3>
  <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
  <div class="button">
   <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Раз уж используете `flex`, почему не посмотрите на https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/?

Comment: У меня v3 в шаблоне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.row-eq-height .col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.row-eq-height .col-sm-4 .button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.row-eq-height .col-sm-4 .button {
   display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-eq-height {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3><span class="label label-primary">1</span> Заголовок</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
      <div class="button">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3><span class="label label-primary">2</span> Заголовок</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum.
      </p>
      <div class="button">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3><span class="label label-primary">3</span> Заголовок</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quidem dignissimos placeat amet fugiat consectetur labore sunt sequi repellat officiis!
      </p>
      <div class="button">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почти получилось! Теперь почему-то кнопки стали на всю ширину блока и не наследуют отступы родителя как другие элементы

Comment: Если убрать класс .btn-block и убрать left: 0, тогда нормально, но как оставить кнопки по всей ширине блока?

Comment: отступы регулируются left и right как и ширину можно задать width

Comment: Если использовать класс .btn-block, то любые значения left и right не дают эффекта...

Comment: .btn-block задает кнопке стили display block width: 100% так что вы еще хотите? конечно кнопка будет на всю ширину блока, убрала этот класс у кнопки

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в рамках данного кода сделать блоки с заголовками одинаковой высоты в независимости от количества текста в них?

Comment: Лучше новым вопросом задайте, пока мыслей что-то нет, возможно кто-то знает)